# How to split the String based on array elements into array retaining the array the split word in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript, split

I have a string

```
sReasons =  "O9C2700021Not eligible for SDWCEOC3900015Service upgradeHJC3900015Service upgradeJ8C5000016Delivery Attempt";
```

and I need to split the above string based on the separator array

```
const separator = ["O9", "EO", "HJ", "J8"];
```

Where first 2 characters(O9) represnet code, next 4 another code(C270) & next 4 the character(0021) length of the String which is Not eligible for SDWC

**Where the separator codes are unique, with 2 capital letters and will not be repeated in `textMessage` except `inEligType`**

I need to create a json of the format

```
{
    {inEligType: "O9", msgCode: "C270", msgLen: "0021", textMsg: "Not eligible for SDWC"},
    {inEligType: "EO", msgCode: "C390", msgLen: "0015", textMsg: "Service upgrade"},
    {inEligType: "HJ", msgCode: "C390", msgLen: "0015", textMsg: "Service upgrade"},
    {inEligType: "J8", msgCode: "C500", msgLen: "0016", textMsg: "Delivery Attempt"}
}
```

I'm basically failing at the splitting the string itself based on the array given, I tried the following

```
sReasons =  "O9C2700021Not eligible for SDWCEOC0900015Service upgradeHJC3900015Service upgradeJ8C5HJ0016Delivery Attempt";    
const separator = ["O9", "EO", "HJ", "J8"];

function formatReasons(Reasons: string) {
var words: any[] = Reasons.split(this.spearator); 
for(let word in words)
    {
       console.log(word) ;
    }
}
var result = formatReasons(sHdnReasonsCreate);
console.log("Returned Result: "+result);
```

But it gives me result as

```
["O9C2700021Not eligible for SDWCEOC0900015Service upgradeHJC3900015Service upgradeJ8C5HJ0016Delivery Attempt"]length: 1__proto__: Array(0)

Returned Address is: undefined
```

Comment: And what will you do if one of the two-letter strings used as a separator happens to appear in the middle of the `textMessage` field?  You'd be much better off splitting this according to the actual data format, by taking substrings of the appropriate length

Comment: They will not be appearing as these are unique and formed to not be coming in `textMessage` or `msgCode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Regex-based approach:

```
sReasons =  "O9C2700021Not eligible for SDWCEOC0900015Service upgradeHJC3900015Service upgradeJ8C5HJ0016Delivery Attempt";    
const separator = ["O9", "EO", "HJ", "J8"];

// build the regex based on separators
let regexPattern = '^';
separator.forEach(text => {
    regexPattern += `${text}(.*)`;
});
regexPattern += '$';

// match the reasons
let r = new RegExp(regexPattern);
let matches = sReasons.match(r);

// prepare to match each message
let msgMatcher = new RegExp('^(?<msgCode>.{4})(?<msgLen>.{4})(?<textMsg>.*)$');
let output = [];

for (let i=1; i<matches.length; i++) {
    // match the message
    const msg = matches[i].match(msgMatcher);

    // store
    let item = msg.groups;
    item.inEligType = separator[i-1];
    output.push(item);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

Produces

```
[
  {
    "msgCode": "C270",
    "msgLen": "0021",
    "textMsg": "Not eligible for SDWC",
    "inEligType": "O9"
  },
  {
    "msgCode": "C090",
    "msgLen": "0015",
    "textMsg": "Service upgrade",
    "inEligType": "EO"
  },
  {
    "msgCode": "C390",
    "msgLen": "0015",
    "textMsg": "Service upgrade",
    "inEligType": "HJ"
  },
  {
    "msgCode": "C5HJ",
    "msgLen": "0016",
    "textMsg": "Delivery Attempt",
    "inEligType": "J8"
  }
]
```

Comment: Of course, this only works for this particular example.

Comment: @georg How so, and what abstract other examples do you propose applying it to? It can withstand changes in `separator` without any modifications of the logic, and the two string lengths hard-coded to 4 are defined that way, but with a direct way of changing them.

Comment: You're assuming that each "separator" occurs exactly once and they always come in the given order. That might not be true in the general case.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Yes there is a better way to generalize it, like the answer I see by @tarkh, I'd revise it to an approach similar to that one.

Answer (score 1):

It may well be that `textMsg` field, nor any other field, will *never* contain the two-letter strings you are using for the `inEligType` field.  But are you absolutely sure of that?  The data format looks to me like it really wants someone to parse it by substrings of certain lengths; why even have a `msgLen` field if you could just split based on delimiters?  What if the list of `inEligType` codes changes in the future?

For these reasons I strongly recommend that you parse by substring lengths and not by delimiter matching.  Here's one possible way to do that:

```
function formatReasons(reasons: string) {
  const ret = []
  while (reasons) {
    const inEligType = reasons.substring(0, 2);
    reasons = reasons.substring(2);
    const msgCode = reasons.substring(0, 4);
    reasons = reasons.substring(4);
    const msgLen = reasons.substring(0, 4);
    reasons = reasons.substring(4);
    const textMsg = reasons.substring(0, +msgLen);
    reasons = reasons.substring(+msgLen);
    ret.push({ inEligType, msgCode, msgLen, textMsg });
  }
  return ret;
}
```

You can verify that it produces the expected output for your example `sReasons` string:

```
const formattedReasons = formatReasons(sReasons);
console.log(JSON.stringify(formattedReasons, undefined, 2));
/* [
  {
    "inEligType": "O9",
    "msgCode": "C270",
    "msgLen": "0021",
    "textMsg": "Not eligible for SDWC"
  },
  {
    "inEligType": "EO",
    "msgCode": "C090",
    "msgLen": "0015",
    "textMsg": "Service upgrade"
  },
  {
    "inEligType": "HJ",
    "msgCode": "C390",
    "msgLen": "0015",
    "textMsg": "Service upgrade"
  },
  {
    "inEligType": "J8",
    "msgCode": "C5HJ",
    "msgLen": "0016",
    "textMsg": "Delivery Attempt"
  }
] */
```

Note that the implementation above does not check that the string is properly formatted; right now if you pass garbage in, you get garbage out.  If you want more safety you could do runtime checks and throw errors if you, say, run off the end of the `reasons` string unexpectedly, or find a `msgLen` field that doesn't represent a number.  And one could [refactor](https://tsplay.dev/mA7JPw) so that there's no repetition of code like `const s = reasons.substring(0, n); reasons = reasons.substring(n)`. But the basic algorithm is there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBBBKBTAhhcEYF4YCIDyAnAMIBMA7AAxUkCMAciLIgDYCWA5qwEbOIwBmIAE4wAygBEA6kQCieIhQJUKNAKyjEQgG6tgfAK4AHdkOQATRAAkAUkQDMSqmo3bdB46YvWAHEVU2nADZxFlYtTQBPGABBKChEAFtDKBwAbgBYACgs-n0wYChWcAFhBOQoJFR0AAohFDRIAC44KCFWMHYAShgAbyyYGFBIWDrYbABtAF1+mAB3AAtWXhha+vRuvsyBgaHoGHaZNnYAFQjDPmw6qsgAOgh9Lmg2juqKABoYEk6Mre2rhowlzWt3uj1a7XY1S+P22g3QsASEHYRBAFiwMH+6DuDyeENeHwALN8ZgNMZB0WSINiwc9IUSYdtdgikQAZRBgCnAqmg3Evd4wekkjFcznXbk48EvQW-HbwmDxAAeUAAskjRQDqbzIfyANSI9hssDEmXCsXqrE8yWQvWs9nG2GjG6GfQQebVHr7MCHDinc4ffUoiz+21gD6KlVqgC+9pgkZmo30Qg5ox+ceymSZJSEZTiiDMlQB6ME2fKBZqCC5xt2IF4N2YIEh1lEeDodytrH4EWqxZz8XzXI+eQs-HaeY+X2NAHoAFQwcYzTawnAHI6+xA4Zr4Ag4N5CnAB1HrzekSg7vf6w0b3DUGhnk04cOq9hXnAMJhHbjLYtiKREHAzSNd1+RdtmXL1VzOI9cDkO8lwPCwXwUJRYNAi92RfJxVBQgYH0QJUnxfFwdD0GAjBMcx1wAoCBhAnCVx9SCXxsbDcHgqCcHsZDqNQkMMJULDuJwx8kUIzRiPcciEKohc93ok5GM3HwWP3JFA3YvxmME1jeM3IJlOE59NxCNhwiEKJYniJIUgArJJhgadJyAA)

Answer (score 0):

Another option with RegExp with less code

```js
// Your data
const data =  "O9C2700021Not eligible for SDWCEOC3900015Service upgradeHJC3900015Service upgradeJ8C5000016Delivery Attempt";

// Set your data splitters from array
const spl = ["O9", "EO", "HJ", "J8"].join('|');

// Use regexp to parse data
const results = [];
data.replace(new RegExp(`(${spl})(\\w{4})(\\w{4})(.*?)(?=${spl}|$)`, 'g'), (m,a,b,c,d) => {
  // Form objects and push to res
  results.push({
    inEligType: a,
    msgCode: b,
    msgLen: c,
    textMsg: d
  });
});

// Result
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

A first approach, based on a [groups capturing regex](https://regex101.com/r/tatBAB/1) consumed by [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), processed by a helper function and finally [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works)d to the expected result ...

```js
function chunkRight(arr, chunkLength) {
  const list = []; 
  arr = [...arr];
  while (arr.length >= chunkLength) {
    list.unshift(
      arr.splice(-chunkLength)
    );
  }
  return list;
}

// see also ... [https://regex101.com/r/tatBAB/1]
// with e.g.
// (?<inEligType>O9|EO|HJ|J8)(?<msgCode>\w{4})(?<msgLen>\d{4})
// ... or ...
// (O9|EO|HJ|J8)(\w{4})(\d{4})
//
function extractStatusItems(str, separators) {
  const regXSplit = RegExp(`(${ separators.join('|') })(\\w{4})(\\d{4})`);

  const statusValues = String(str).split(regXSplit).slice(1);
  const groupedValues = chunkRight(statusValues, 4);

  return groupedValues.reduce((list, [inEligType, msgCode, msgLen, textMsg]) =>
    list.concat({ inEligType, msgCode, msgLen, textMsg }), []
  );
}

const statusCode = 'O9C2700021Not eligible for SDWCEOC3900015Service upgradeHJC3900015Service upgradeJ8C5000016Delivery Attempt';

console.log(
  `statusCode ... ${ statusCode } ...`,
  extractStatusItems(statusCode, ['O9', 'EO', 'HJ', 'J8'])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... followed by a second approach, based almost entirely on a [regex which captures named groups](https://regex101.com/r/tatBAB/2), consumed by [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and finally [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ped into the expected result ...

```js
// see also ... [https://regex101.com/r/tatBAB/2]
// with e.g.
// (?<inEligType>O9|EO|HJ|J8)(?<msgCode>\w{4})(?<msgLen>\d{4})(.*?)(?<textMsg>.*?)(?=O9|EO|HJ|J8|$)
//
function extractStatusItems(str, separators) {
  separators = separators.join('|');

  const regXCaptureValues = RegExp(
    `(?<inEligType>${ separators })(?<msgCode>\\w{4})(?<msgLen>\\d{4})(.*?)(?<textMsg>.*?)(?=${ separators }|$)`, 
    'g'
  );
  return [
    ...String(str).matchAll(regXCaptureValues)
  ].map(
    ({ groups }) => ({ ...groups })
  );
}

const statusCode = 'O9C2700021Not eligible for SDWCEOC3900015Service upgradeHJC3900015Service upgradeJ8C5000016Delivery Attempt';

console.log(
  `statusCode ... ${ statusCode } ...`,
  extractStatusItems(statusCode, ['O9', 'EO', 'HJ', 'J8'])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```